# Python: plot a graph / distribution of data from total to parts

Tags: python, plot, graph

Let's say i've got some data in the shape of

[image: data sample]

where each row represents how a total (83 in the first one) distributes over some groupings (columns).

[image: Target graph]

is there a way to generate this kind of graphs in matplotlib, or otherwise in some other lib in Python? Final result should be a sequence of graphs like the one shown in picture, stacked horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `networkx` python module to do so; you can install it from `pip` or `conda` like so:

```
# pip
pip install networkx

# conda
conda install -c anaconda networkx
```

After installing it, you need to use the following function that returns a graph and its parameters based on a list of three values as shown in your question:

```py
def create_graph(values):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('a','c'), ('a','d')])
    _sum = sum(values)
    labels = {'a': _sum, 'b':values[0], 'c':values[1], 'd':values[2]}
    sizes = [50 * _sum, 50*values[0], 50*values[1], 50*values[2]]
    return G, labels, sizes
```

Now, let's see how to use this function:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2, 42], "B": [41, 1], "C":[40, 27]})

# create subplot based on the number of rows in df
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=df.shape[0], ncols=1, figsize=(10,10))
ax = axes.flatten()

# iterate over the rows and draw a graph for each one
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    graph, labels, sizes = create_graph(row.values)
    nx.draw(graph, node_size=sizes, labels=labels, ax=ax[i])

# show the result
plt.show()
```

The previous code will result in the following graph:

[image: plot output]